# C Program that prints the source code of a C file with the same name

Tags: c, ubuntu

So I need to write a code with this compilation flags:

> gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall

All on Linux based OS.
The output program should print its own source code. If I change the output file name AND there is a C file with the same name in the folder it would print its content.

Up until now I managed to pull this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c; 
    FILE *my_file = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(my_file);
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(my_file);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I change the file name and the C file name it gives me an error. Example:
For files: prnt.c, prnt

```
Consule -> os/23$ ./prnt
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c; 
    FILE *my_file = fopen(__FILE__, "r");
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(my_file);
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(my_file);
    return 0;
}
```

for same file after I change the name to test.c, test (with out compilation)

```
/os/23$ ./test 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It is happening because of the __ *FILE* __ macro, it changes after compilation to the original file name. The question is how do I solve this problem?

Comment: First: `int c;` ... then check the return value of `fopen()`: ie `if (my_file == NULL) { perror(__FILE__); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "change the output file name", but I expect you need to look at `argv[0]` for the name the binary was executed as on the command line.

Comment: Hm, the source file would need to be part of the final executable. You might rely on the source residing parallelly to the executable and cut away the path from `__FILE__`.

Comment: `while (c != EOF)` is undefined behaviour, by the way, as `c` is not initialised! You might initialise to `~EOF` to make assure it being different from. And it should be of type `int` to guarantee a byte `0xff` really differ from EOF (apparently your `char` is signed anyway, otherwise you'd end up in an endless loop!).

Comment: And you'll be printing the `EOF` value as well, which is not part of your source file! You might try with `for(;;) { int c = fgetc(my_file); if(c == EOF) { break; } putchar(c); }`

Comment: Why not add a `printf ("File: %s\n", __FILE__ );` to then see what is actually happening.

Comment: You probably misunderstand the assignment. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: After `FILE *my_file = fopen(__FILE__, "r");` check for valid `my_file`.  Something like `if(NULL != my_file)` - then only proceed with reading the file.  Mostly `my_file' is not valid  - hence segmentation fault

Comment: If you don't want to mess around determining file names and trying to open them, see [question 20.34](http://c-faq.com/misc/quine.html) of the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).  This is the usual thing people are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

So I checked into **Paul Hankin's** suggestion, I managed to solve the problem.
Hope that in the future it will help somebody.

My Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
    This program prints the source code
    of the 'C' file with the same name in the
    same directory.
    */
    char c = 'a'; /* Initialization before while loop.*/
    char* locat = argv[0]; /* The path to the program file.*/
    char suff[3] = ".c\0";
    FILE* my_file;

    strcat(locat, suff); /* Doesn't work for Windows.*/

    my_file = fopen(locat, "r");
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(my_file);
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(my_file);
    return 0;
}
```